# Notate merged questions on front page

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, information-display, merged-questions

I went into [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/165789/difference-between-csv-in-excel-and-csv-in-openoffice) that I'd flagged for merging to see if anything had happened on it, and sure enough it had been merged.

Could we get a notation like **[merged]** on the front page for these types of questions?  A migrated question shows [closed] at least.

Comment: I'd be fine with [closed] on these also.

Comment: If two questions are merged, does the source question persist in question lists? I would have thought it would be like a deleted question where it will show up only until the next cache refresh.

Comment: @Lance: Can you link to the question?  I thought there already was a [merged] note.

Comment: Just found one. It says [closed]. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/why-is-alt-gr-q-giving-me-quote-formatting-instead-of-the-sign-closed @Bill

Comment: But that one had already been closed. What happens if a question is merged before it is closed? @Jon @Bill

Comment: @Lance: Thanks, I just misunderstood you.  You want the annotation in the title so it shows up on the main page.  My bad, I thought you were asking for a note on the question itself.

Comment: @Bill, yep, that's what I want, it always saves time to have that little bit of information up front.

Comment: @mmyers: Good point. Maybe create a couple of test questions, merge them together and see what happens.